# vbscript static class variables/methods?

Tags: oop, vbscript, static-methods, static-variables, class-method

Is there a way to have one variable per class in vbscript?

If not what is the best way to emulate it? Prefixing a global variable declared next to the class?

Also is there a way to declare static/class methods(for a static constructor) or am I force to prefix a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In languages that support class-level/static data or methods you can

1. associate/bind data or methods explicitly to the set of objects defined by the class. So you can have Customer.Count **and** Product.Count and a plain Count (or @@Count) in Customer code will access the right number.
2. use such data or method without having an instance of the class (yet).

VBScript does not support static data or methods. You have to use global data or functions/subs and do the associating in your mind (perhaps with a little help from a naming convention). Accessing these 'static'=global elements without an object is trivial, but - obviously - should be done with care.

You can embed one or more singleton objects or code references (GetRef()) in your objects to bind them closer to the class, but that will increase the size of the instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to sort of emulate a static class:

```vb
Class Defines_
   Public Sub DoSomethingUseful
   End Sub
End Class

Dim Defines : Set Defines = New Defines_
...

Defines.DoSomethingUseful
```

This can be used to give you something analogous to constructors (really, factory methods):

```
Class Something
   Private mValue
   Public Property Get Value : Value = mValue : End Property
   Public Property Let Value(x) : mValue = x : End Property
End Class

Class SomethingFactory_
   Public Function Create(value)
      Set Create = New Something
      Create.Value = value
   End Function
End Class
Dim SomethingFactory : Set SomethingFactory = New SomethingFactory_
...

Dim something : Set something = SomethingFactory.Create(5)
```